# BackboneJS passing parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone App where I fetch data through RESTful API from my MySQL DB. Now I want to fetch specific Videos which are associated to a specific artist_id, but no matter what Artist I choose in the end, it displays ALL videos and in my console I get `../api/videos/artist_videos/undefined` - So somehow, the artist_id is not getting passed on.

So my artistVideo.js looks like:

```
function (App, Backbone) {

    var ArtistVideos = App.module();

    ArtistVideos.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'artistVideos',
        template: 'single_video',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
        },
        serialize: function() {
            return this.model.toJSON();
        },          
        beforeRender: function(){
            $('ul.acmenu li a.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $('ul.acmenu li a.artistVideos').addClass('selected');
        }

    });

    ArtistVideos.ArtistVideosModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot: '../index.php/api/videos/artist_videos/' + this.artist_id,
            defaults: {
                "not categorized": [],
                "live": [],
                "others": []
            }
    });

    return ArtistVideos;
}
```

Then my mainView, artistVideoPage.js, where I include the above file:

```
define([

'app',
'backbone',
'modules/artistImage',
'modules/artistName',
'modules/artistVideos',
],

function (App, Backbone, Artistimg, Artistname, ArtistVideos ) {

    var ArtistVideo = App.module();

    ArtistVideo.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'artist',
        template: 'artistVideoPage',
        beforeRender: function() {          
            var artistimgCollection = new Artistimg.ArtistimgCollection();
            artistimgCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.artistImage', new Artistimg.View({collection: artistimgCollection}));
            artistimgCollection.fetch();

            var artistnameCollection = new Artistname.ArtistnameCollection();
            artistnameCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.artistName', new Artistname.View({collection: artistnameCollection}));
            artistnameCollection.fetch();

            var artistvideosModel = new ArtistVideos.ArtistVideosModel();
            artistvideosModel.artist_id = this.artist_id;
            this.insertView('.artistVideosDiv', new ArtistVideos.View({model: artistvideosModel}));
            artistvideosModel.fetch();
        }       
    });

    return ArtistVideo;
});
```

Finally, I have a controller, which looks like this:

```
ArtistController.prototype.initVideos = function(id) {
    this.artistVideosView.artist_id = id;
    this.artistNavigation.artist_id = id;
    App.useLayout('artistVideoPage', 'artistVideoPage').setViews({
        '.videosDiv': this.artistVideosView,
        '.artistTopMenu': this.artistNavigation
    }).render();
};
```

I tried to do `console.log(this.artist_id)` - It actually displays the right ID, but i still get `../api/videos/artist_videos/undefined`

Does anyone know what is the issue here? Why do I get `undefined`?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed it myself!

the issue was the `urlRoot` - apparently it tried to define `this.artist_id` right away, but it didnt exist at that time. So changing it to:

```
url: function() {
    return '../index.php/api/videos/artist_videos/' + this.artist_id;
},
```

solved the problem!

Comment: You probably should mark this answer as *Accepted* by clicking the check-mark on the left ([even though it's your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) (though you won't get the +2 rep in that case) this will indicate to others who may come across your problem in the future that there is an *Accepted* answer (i.e a solution to the problem).